# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ when $\sum_{n=1}^M a_n $ is bounded and $b_n \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers and let there exist $C>0$ such that  $|\sum_{n=1}^M a_n |\leq C$ for every $M$. Let $(b_n)$ be another complex sequence that tends to zero: $b_n \to 0$, as ${n\to\infty}$.

Is it true that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$$
converges?

I know it doesn't necessarily converge absolutely (take, for example, $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$).

It seems a bit similar to the [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) case.
How about if we also assume that $b_n$ are real, positive and monotonically decreasing? I try to prove that partial sums are a cauchy sequence in this case:

$$|a_mb_m+a_{m+1}b_{m+1}+...+a_{m+d}b_{m+d}|$$

I would like to take $b_m$ out, but I still have a problem, since I don't know how to bound the sum $|a_m+a_{m+1}\frac{b_{m+1}}{b_m}+...+a_{m+d}\frac{b_{m+d}}{b_m}|$ (I can't use triangle inequality since the sum of absolute values of $a_n$'s need not be bounded.)

Is there a way to prove this (with the additional assumption on $(b_n)$) or is there a counterexample showing that this sort of hypothesis can't be true at all and maybe works just in some particular cases (like the alternating series)?

Comment: Can't you get divergence from something like $a_n = (-1)^n, b_{2n} = 1/n, b_{2n+1} = 0$? Edit: I remembered that [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) is a version of this with strengthened hypotheses.

Comment: Thanks! That's excatly what I wanted, the assumption "$b_n$ decreases monotonically" is needed (or at least we have convergence when this happens).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that a complex number $\sum a_n$ is less than some number $C$.  Do you mean $\left|\sum a_n\right|<C$?

Comment: The monotonicity obviously does not have to apply for the entire sequence - only that there exists a number $N$ such that $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing for $n>N$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes. I meant bounded. I'll edit.